# ¿Cómo usar "OR" en lugar de "AND" con múltiples .Where en LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Estoy queriendo hacer una query dinámica, en la cual mediante un for por cada iteracion esta vaya
concatenando cada estado pero LINQ por defecto
me deja la clausula "AND" a medida que recorre el for por lo que yo necesito usar "OR" por cada dato recorrido, hay alguna manera
de setear por defecto que use or?

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < estados.Count; i++)
{                    
    query = query.Where(p => p.Estado == estados[i].Id);
}
```

Comment: Hola Esteban, este es el sitio en español de StackOverflow.  Por favor traduce tu pregunta :).

Comment: Tu código no esta completo, ¿podrías por favor complementarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que parece que estás intentando hacer es consultar todos los elementos con un Id dentro de la lista `estados`, entonces te sugiero una alternativa a concatenar condiciones:

```
var ids = estados.Select(e => e.Id).ToList();

query.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Estado));
```

Solo eso, sin necesidad del `for`.  El query que se generará será similar a

```
SELECT ....
FROM Table
WHERE Estado IN (e1, e2, e3 ...)
```

Comment: Anduvo perfecto Gracias!!! Me salvaste

Answer (score 2):

Pero no necesitas concatenar condiciones con un bucle si lo que quieres es obtener aquellos elementos cuya propiedad Estado coincida con alguno de los Ids de los elementos de estados te basta con:

```
query = query.Where(p => estados.Any(e => e.Id == p.Estado));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la pregunta ya este respuesta, añado una puntualización que tiene que ver con la pregunta.

Para concatenar condiciones con linq puedes usar **PredicateBuilder**

Esta clase añade metodos de extension a la clase **Expression** y uno de ellos es **Or** con el cual puedes preparar una query Linq de forma dinamica.

**PredicateBuilder** está incluido dentro del paquete **LinqKit**

[Ejemplo Claro de Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Saludos!